# Few PrimeFaces dialogs are displayed instead of one on validation fail

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 3.5 application. 
home.xhtml page contains a tabView with 3 nested dataTables and CRUD buttons in each of them.

Each from CRUD buttons call a dialog window with different form. The problem is that whenever one of the dialogs get validation errors - all other dialogs are displayed too because their attribute is `visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"` (IMHO)

I need to display only one dialog which failed to validate untill user enters valid values or presses Cancel button (clears dialog form values).

Every answer is highly appreciated.

home.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
              xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
              xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
              xmlns:ex="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/nsobchuk">
    <h:head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form id="logout" class="logout" >
            <h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.logout()}" value="logout"/>
        </h:form>

        <p:tabView id="tab" orientation="left">

            <p:tab title="Users">

                <h:form id="form1">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg1.show()"/>

                        <p:dialog id="addUserDialog" header="Add Dialog" modal="true" closable="false"
                                  widgetVar="dlg1" width="620" visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">

                            <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                                <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="login" value="#{homeBean.newUser.login}" required="true"  
                                             label="Login: " maxlength="20">
                                    <f:validator binding="#{loginValidator}"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                                <p:message for="login"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: "/>
                                <p:password id="password" value="#{homeBean.newUser.password}" required="true" 
                                            feedback="true"  label="Password: " maxlength="32"/>
                                <p:message for="password" />

                                <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{homeBean.newUser.firstName}"
                                             label="First Name: " maxlength="20"/>
                                <p:message for="firstName"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{homeBean.newUser.lastName}" 
                                             label="Last Name: " maxlength="20"/>
                                <p:message for="lastName"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="role" value="Role: "/>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{homeBean.newUser.role}" required="true" style="width: 80px;" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="user" itemValue="ROLE_USER" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="admin" itemValue="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <p:message for="role"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlg1.hide()" update=":tab:form1:addUserDialog">
                                <p:resetInput target="addUserDialog"  />
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton value="Add" update=":tab:users, :tab:form1:addUserDialog" process="@this" 
                                             onclick="if (args &amp; &amp; !args.validationFailed) dlg1.hide()" action="#{homeBean.addUser}"/>


                        </p:dialog> 


                        <p:commandButton id="editUser" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg2.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedUser == null}"/>
                        <p:dialog id="editUserDialogerDialog" widgetVar="dlg2" header="Sorry" >
                            <h:outputText value="I didn't have enogh time to finish this functionality. Feel free to test other buttons."/>
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="deleteUser" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedUser == null}"/>
                        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete user?" header="Confirmation"
                                         severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation1">
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:users" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                             oncomplete="confirmation1.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteUser}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>


                <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{homeBean.users}" 
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedUser}" rowKey="#{user.userId}"
                             sortMode="single">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onUserRowSelect}" update=":tab:form1:deleteUser, :tab:form1:editUser"/> 
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{homeBean.onUserRowUnselect}" update=":tab:form1:deleteUser, :tab:form1:editUser"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Login" sortBy="#{user.login}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.login}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Password" sortBy="#{user.password}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.password}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{user.role}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.role}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{user.firstName}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="#{user.lastName}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}"/>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

                <ex:exporter target=":tab:users" fileName="Users"/>

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Computers">

                <h:form id="form2">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg3.show()"/>

                        <p:dialog id="addCompDialog" header="Add Dialog" draggable="true" closable="false" modal="true"
                                  widgetVar="dlg3" width="600" visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}" >


                            <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                                <h:outputLabel for="pclogin" value="Login: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="pclogin" value="#{homeBean.newComputer.login}" required="true"  
                                             label="Login: " maxlength="20">
                                    <f:validator binding="#{loginValidator}"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                                <p:message for="pclogin"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="pcpassword" value="Password: "/>
                                <p:password id="pcpassword" value="#{homeBean.newComputer.password}" required="true" 
                                            feedback="true"  label="Password: " maxlength="32"/>
                                <p:message for="pcpassword" />

                                <h:outputLabel for="compName" value="Computer Name: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="compName" value="#{homeBean.newComputer.computerName}" required="true"
                                             label="Computer Name: " maxlength="20"/>
                                <p:message for="compName"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="ipaddress" value="IP address: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="ipaddress" value="#{homeBean.newComputer.ipAddress}" required="true"
                                             label="IP address: " maxlength="20"/>
                                <p:message for="ipaddress"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlg3.hide()" update=":tab:form2:addCompDialog">
                                <p:resetInput target="addCompDialog" />
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton value="Add" update=":tab:computers, :tab:form2:addCompDialog" process="@this" 
                                             onclick="if (args &amp; &amp; !args.validationFailed) dlg3.hide()" action="#{homeBean.addComputer}"/>


                        </p:dialog> 


                        <p:commandButton id="editComp" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg4.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedComputer == null}"/>
                        <p:dialog id="editCompDialog" widgetVar="dlg4" header="Sorry" >
                            <h:outputText value="I didn't have enogh time to finish this functionality. Feel free to test other buttons."/>
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="deleteComp" type="button" onclick="confirmation2.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedComputer == null}"/>
                        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete this computer?" header="Confirmation"
                                         severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation2">
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:computers" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                             oncomplete="confirmation2.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteComputer}"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation2.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>


                <p:dataTable id="computers" var="computer" value="#{homeBean.computers}" 
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedComputer}" rowKey="#{computer.computerId}"
                             sortMode="single" >
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onCompRowSelect}" update=":tab:form2:editComp, :tab:form2:deleteComp"/> 

                    <p:column headerText="Login" sortBy="#{computer.login}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.login}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Password" sortBy="#{computer.password}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.password}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{computer.computerName}" > 
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.computerName}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="IP address" sortBy="#{computer.ipAddress}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.ipAddress}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

                <ex:exporter target=":tab:computers" fileName="Computers"/>

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Applications">


                <h:form id="form3">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg5.show()"/>

                        <p:dialog id="addAppDialog" header="Add Dialog" draggable="true" closable="false" modal="true"
                                  widgetVar="dlg5" width="600" visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}" >


                            <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                                <h:outputLabel for="appName" value="Name: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="appName" value="#{homeBean.newApplication.appName}" required="true"  
                                             label="Name: "/>
                                <p:message for="appName"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="vendorName" value="Vendor: "/>
                                <p:inputText id="vendorName" value="#{homeBean.newApplication.vendorName}"
                                             label="Vendor: " required="true" />
                                <p:message for="vendorName"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="appLicense" value="Requires license: "/>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="appLicense" value="#{homeBean.newApplication.licenseRequired}" required="true" style="width: 80px;" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="#{true}" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="#{false}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <p:message for="appLicense"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlg5.hide()" update=":tab:form3:addAppDialog">
                                <p:resetInput target="addAppDialog" />
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton value="Add" update=":tab:applications, :tab:form3:addAppDialog" process="@this" 
                                             onclick="if (args &amp; &amp; !args.validationFailed) dlg5.hide()" action="#{homeBean.addApplication}"/>


                        </p:dialog> 


                        <p:commandButton id="editApp" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg6.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedApplication == null}"/>
                        <p:dialog id="editAppDialog" widgetVar="dlg6" header="Sorry" >
                            <h:outputText value="I didn't have enogh time to finish this functionality. Feel free to test other buttons."/>
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="deleteApp" type="button" onclick="confirmation3.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedApplication == null}"/>
                        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete this application?" header="Confirmation"
                                         severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation3">
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:applications" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                             oncomplete="confirmation3.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteApplication}"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation3.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>

                <p:dataTable id="applications" var="app" value="#{homeBean.applications}" 
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedApplication}" rowKey="#{app.appId}"
                             sortMode="single" >

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onAppRowSelect}" update=":tab:form3:editApp, :tab:form3:deleteApp"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{app.appName}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{app.appName}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Vendor" sortBy="#{app.vendorName}" >  
                        <h:outputText value="#{app.vendorName}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="License required" sortBy="#{app.licenseRequired}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{app.licenseRequired}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

                <ex:exporter target=":tab:applications" fileName="Applications" />

            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>

    </h:body>

</ui:component>
```

HomeBean.java:

```
package com.infostroy.adminportal.controller.bean;

import com.infostroy.adminportal.bean.BaseBean;
import com.infostroy.adminportal.model.Application;
import com.infostroy.adminportal.model.Computer;
import com.infostroy.adminportal.model.User;
import com.infostroy.adminportal.service.HibernateDBManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.List;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class HomeBean extends BaseBean {

    private static final String editUserBtn = "tab:form1:editUser";
    private static final String deleteUserBtn = "tab:form1:deleteUser";
    private static final String editCompBtn = "tab:form2:editComp";
    private static final String deleteCompBtn = "tab:form2:deleteComp";
    private static final String editAppBtn = "tab:form3:editApp";
    private static final String deleteAppBtn = "tab:form3:deleteApp";
    @Autowired
    private HibernateDBManager hibernateDBManager;
    private List<User> users;
    private List<Computer> computers;
    private List<Application> applications;
    private User selectedUser, newUser;
    private Computer selectedComputer, newComputer;
    private Application selectedApplication, newApplication;
    private RequestContext rc;


    @Override
    public void init() {
        setUsers(hibernateDBManager.getAllUsers());
        setComputers(hibernateDBManager.getAllComputers());
        setApplications(hibernateDBManager.getAllApplications());
        newUser = new User();
        newComputer = new Computer();
        newApplication = new Application();
        rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    public void addUser() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (newUser != null && newUser.getPassword() != null) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(newUser.getPassword().getBytes());
            String hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
            newUser.setPassword(hash);
            if (hibernateDBManager.insertUser(newUser)) {
                users.add(newUser);
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteUser() throws IOException {
        if (selectedUser != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteUserById(selectedUser.getUserId()) > 0) {
                users.remove(selectedUser);
                selectedUser = null;
                rc.update(deleteUserBtn);
                rc.update(editUserBtn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addComputer() {
        if (newComputer != null && hibernateDBManager.insertComputer(newComputer)) {
            computers.add(newComputer);
        }
    }

    public void deleteComputer() {
        if (selectedComputer != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteComputerById(selectedComputer.getComputerId()) > 0) {
                computers.remove(selectedComputer);
                selectedComputer = null;
                rc.update(editCompBtn);
                rc.update(deleteCompBtn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addApplication() {
        if (newApplication != null && hibernateDBManager.insertApplication(newApplication)) {
            applications.add(newApplication);
        }
    }

    public void deleteApplication() {
        if (selectedApplication != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteApplicationById(selectedApplication.getAppId()) > 0) {
                applications.remove(selectedApplication);
                selectedApplication = null;
                rc.update(editAppBtn);
                rc.update(deleteAppBtn);
            }
        }
    }


    public void onUserRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedUser((User) event.getObject());
    }

    public void onUserRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        setSelectedUser(null);
    }

    public void onCompRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedComputer((Computer) event.getObject());
    }

    public void onAppRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedApplication((Application) event.getObject());
    }

    public List<Computer> getComputers() {
        return computers;
    }

    public void setComputers(List<Computer> computers) {
        this.computers = computers;
    }

    public List<Application> getApplications() {
        return applications;
    }

    public void setApplications(List<Application> applications) {
        this.applications = applications;
    }

    public Computer getSelectedComputer() {
        return selectedComputer;
    }

    public void setSelectedComputer(Computer selectedComputer) {
        this.selectedComputer = selectedComputer;
    }

    public Application getSelectedApplication() {
        return selectedApplication;
    }

    public void setSelectedApplication(Application selectedApplication) {
        this.selectedApplication = selectedApplication;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public User getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }

    public User getNewUser() {
        return newUser;
    }

    public void setNewUser(User newUser) {
        this.newUser = newUser;
    }

    public Computer getNewComputer() {
        return newComputer;
    }

    public void setNewComputer(Computer newComputer) {
        this.newComputer = newComputer;
    }

    public Application getNewApplication() {
        return newApplication;
    }

    public void setNewApplication(Application newApplication) {
        this.newApplication = newApplication;
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using the visible attribute? you should handle visibility using dlg.open() and dlg.hide when appropiate. Also, IMHO I think it's better to put the dialogs at the end of the page (outside tabView), and each one with its own form.

Comment: I am using visible attribute because I need a dialog to be visible if validation has failed and to display validation error.

Comment: that is handled differently, not the visible attribute. for that, you can use RequestContext params (which I think you are using based on the code of the onclick attribute. Look at this showcase example of primefaces that shows how to keep the dialog visible with validation messages: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf

Comment: I would be eternally thankful if you could provide me with some code to solve this cuz I'm realy stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Several PrimeFaces dialogs show up on validation error instead of single](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316053/several-primefaces-dialogs-show-up-on-validation-error-instead-of-single)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the code for the first dialog. I removed the closable="false" because in my opinion it's not a good idea. user may have clicked by accident or changed his mind, so why not let him close the dialog? otherwise hr'll have to refresh the page.

```
<p:dialog id="addUserDialog" header="Add Dialog" modal="true" closable="false"
          widgetVar="dlg1" width="620" >

      <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <!-- input fields -->
      </h:panelGrid>

      <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlg1.hide()"
                       update=":tab:form1:addUserDialog">
              <p:resetInput target="addUserDialog"  />
       </p:commandButton>

       <p:commandButton value="Add" update=":tab:users, :tab:form1:addUserDialog" 
                        actionListener="#{homeBean.addUser}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

In the managed bean:

```
public void addUser() {
    // this check is not really necessary. newUser is never null, and the password too since there is a required validation in the jsf page
    if (newUser != null && newUser.getPassword() != null) { 
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(newUser.getPassword().getBytes());
            String hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
            newUser.setPassword(hash);
            if (hibernateDBManager.insertUser(newUser)) {
                users.add(newUser);
            }
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlg1.hide()");
            newUser = new User(); // you were missing this
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
             // log exception and show nice message
        }
    }
}
```

Repeat the same for the other dialogs.

Comment: Thank you, Damian! Could you please also have a look at my other question. There are some weird things happening!

Comment: link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330504/multiple-primefaces-dialogs-on-one-page